# Needed: Example of replacing html5lib sanitizer

Tags: python-3.x, django-cms, html5lib

djangocms_text_ckeditor references the html5lib sanitizer function, which has been deprecated.

I expect that there is a way to rewrite this code without sanitizer.

from html5lib import sanitizer

sanitizer.HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements.extend(settings.TEXT_ADDITIONAL_TAGS)

Any suggestions?  5 lines of code are really holding me back from upgrading my whole project to current ubuntu, django and python.

It seems to be solved:  https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/72
But an example of how to rewrite the code would be really helpful.  I don't know why djangocms_text_ckedit hasn't made these changes to the code already.

Comment: Probably best to ask here: https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor/issues

Comment: It seems that the html5lib people would be able to recommend a solution to the change, and then the djangocms team implement it right?